# Why do Font Awesome icons render in SVG format?

Tags: css, angular, font-awesome

In my Angular5 project I use FontAwesome icons: static icon and spinner.
I ran npm install font-awesome and version 4.7.0 was installed.

```
"dependencies": {
  ....
  "font-awesome": "4.7.0"
}
```

in my app.component.html

```
<div class="center">
  <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
  <p>Loading...</p>
</div>
```

But what I see in dev console in chrome: 
[image]

And spinner doesn't have correct pulse-like animation.

If I use static font awesome icon, it also renders as SVG. Why?

Answer (score 4):

Because you are using as a package as dependency, that is normal based on the docs: https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/svg-with-js

> Our brand new SVG-based framework that gives you all the benefits of using SVG icons on the web without all of the hassle. We’ve kept the syntax and steps simple, and built tools for sizing, placement, and styling on top of that.

If you want to use it differently I would add it as font in css/sass file or:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/vX.XX.XX/css/all.css"
```

Docs: https://fontawesome.com/get-started/web-fonts-with-css

And not as js library: https://fontawesome.com/get-started/svg-with-js